# How to set scroll bar position in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0.

I have jsff fragment with two panels.
Left side panel contains links and the right side panel will show the data depend on the link clicked on the left side panel.

Links in the left side panel are rendered using iterator and this iterator is resided in panelGroupLayout with layout="scroll".

When I scroll down to the end of the left side panel and click on the link, then the content in the right side panel is loading fine, but the scroll bar of the left side panel is resetting to top. So that I am not able to see the selected link in the left side panel.

Is there a way to fix the scroll bar at the same position ?

```
<af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl3" layout="horizontal" valign="top" inlineStyle="height:200px;" styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
    <af:panelGroupLayout layout="scroll" halign="left" id="pgl4" inlineStyle="width:100px;"
        partialTriggers="i1:cl1">
        <af:iterator value="#{pageFlowScope.headerBean.links}" id="i1" var="link">
            <af:commandLink actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.headerBean.linkCliked}" id="cl1" inlineStyle="border: solid 1px black;"
                            partialSubmit="true">
                <af:outputText value="#{link}" id="ot6" 
                               styleClass="selectedLinkStyle"
                               rendered="#{pageFlowScope.headerBean.selectedLink}"/>
                <af:outputText value="#{link}" id="ot7" 
                               styleClass="unselectedLinkStyle"
                               rendered="#{not pageFlowScope.headerBean.selectedLink}"/>
                <f:attribute name="selectedLinkName"
                                         value="#{link}"/>
            </af:commandLink>
        </af:iterator>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
    <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" halign="right"
                         id="pgl5" inlineStyle="border: solid 1px black;height:200px;"
                         partialTriggers="i1:cl1">
        <af:outputText value="#{pageFlowScope.headerBean.linkData} id="ot5"/>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the partialTriggers attribute of **pgl4** 
Or consider using [Active Data](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31974/adv_ads.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the scrollComponentIntoViewBehavior as described [in here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFUI/af_event.htm#DAFEEGCI) but this is a new feature in 12c